# how to draw a bar graph with tow y- axis in iOS?

Tags: iphone, core-plot, bar-chart

I am using core-plot framework for drawing graphs. But I need to draw two bars with two y-axis. Please help providing sample code/example links.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please can you explain what you mean by two y axis. Surely a graph only has one y axis?

Comment: @Fogmeister, No a graph can contain multiple y axis one is left side and another one is right side of the graph. But this two y-axis contain only one x-axis.

Comment: Oh, I see :D, I understand what you mean now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirement this bellow link is very useful to you..also in this example many graphs and charts available

[MIMChart-Library](https://github.com/ReetuRaj/MIMChart-Library)

and this tutorial with core-plot library

1. [how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2)
2. [using-core-plot-to-draw-line-graphs](http://www.springtiger.co.uk/2010/10/03/using-core-plot-to-draw-line-graphs/)

i hope this help you..

Comment: Thank you for replay. But i need this in core plot, because i already using core-plot in my project.

Comment: @Ram try this may be you can get idea from this tutorial..http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2

Comment: This raywenderlich provides the single y-axis with mulitple bars but my requirement is two y-axis with two bars.

Answer (score 0):

The "Axis Demo" in the *Plot Gallery* example app included with Core Plot shows how to do this. You create another axis and add it to the `axes` array of the axis set. The secondary y-axis can share the same plot space as the other axes or be assigned to another plot space if it needs to have a different scale.